# How do I block Chrome extensions from making network requests unless whitelisted?

Tags: chrome

I see extensions such as uMatrix that allow you to whitelist requests for URL patterns. How can I have the same functionality but, instead of for websites I visit, for Chrome extensions I have installed?

Comment: What are the permissions of the extension?

Comment: Even without explictly-given permission it seems like any extension can make http requests.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this extension ? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-apps-extensions-de/ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc
It's made by Google itself and seems to have the functionnality you need. Since I have Firefox I can't test it myself, but let me know if it works.